# Restose content from revisions - sql query

Tags: sql, backup, phpmyadmin, revisions

How i can restore all posts to the closest revision to a particular date via sql query?

Comment: I would not attempt this in pure SQL.

Comment: I must restore 2000 posts :/

Comment: Still not something for pure SQL. Handle most of the logic in PHP.

Comment: `wp_update_post()` and `wp_get_post_revision()`